# Update GeoServer layer style over the API does not work when styles have the same name

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, rest

So here's my scenario: I have a working integration that syncs layers and styles to geoserver without issues. This is working for a long time, all the calls succeeds as expected.

When I have the following scenario, GeoServer get's a bit confused. The below example tries to show the hierarchy inside GeoServer, composed of workspaces, layers and styles. In the example below I have two workspaces (foo and bar), each with a layer and style. The styles have the same name.

```
workspaces
  - foo_workspace
    - styles
      - style_a
    - layers
      - layer_a
  - bar_workspace
    - styles
      - style_a
    - layers
      - layer_a
```

So, when I update the style programatically, using the `PUT` call to `workspaces/foo_workspace/layers/layer_a` I set the default style, like so (payload below):

```
{
 layer: {
  defaultStyle: {name: "style_a"}
 } 
}
```

The call succeeds! However, in this particular scenario, GeoServer associates styles that are not belonging to this workspace. It seems to be nondeterministic, sometimes it works, sometimes it fails.

I know that in the rest call I can't specify the workspace (as far as I know of), but does anyone know a way to make sure GeoServer picks the correct style, from the correct workspace?

Bonus: this also fails in the admin.

Comment: seems to be a known issue - https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9166 fixes are always gratefully accepted

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton. I'll update the question to have this link so others can have visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known GeoServer issue: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9166

The solution for automations and integrations is to actually have unique style names per workspace.